# Change border Image on Click

Tags: javascript, html, css, border-image

I am attempting to change the border image on click of a radio button and am doing the following:

```
<input type="radio" name="field" value="4" onclick="document.getElementbyId('pet').style.borderImage='url(http://ianon.info/pet_support/borders/pawprint.png) 120 round'"/>
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementbyId is not a function
```

Why does this work for the "border" option but not for the "borderImage" option. I'd like to define it onclick since all the JS functions I am defining in different parts of the document are not being recognized.

Comment: You need to put your JS code into a function. Preferably a function inside a script tag

Comment: @HTMLNoob no they don't

Comment: @HTMLNoob Putting the statements in a function is not necessary though a good practice.

Answer (score 3):

Typo. `document.getElementbyId` should be `document.getElementById`. Notice the capitalization in the function name.

Answer (score 0):

Can defined it as a function in a script and using "getElementById" upper cases for function name.

```
<script>
        function changeimg(){
 document.getElementById('pet').style.borderImage='url(http://ianon.info/pet_support/borders/pawprint.png) 120 round';
        }
       </script>

<body>
<input type="radio" name="field" value="4" onclick= changeimg()/>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You made a spelling error, 
Change `document.getElementbyId`to `document.getElementById`